# How to delete Codeigniter Project via the Admin page in the project by pressing "Delete Project" button

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to delete the Codeigniter Project via the Admin page in the project by pressing the "Delete Project" button?
For example, such as uninstalling Windows applications through the Control Panel.
How is the code written?

- on XAMPP: localhost/**PROJECT**    <- delete this codeigniter project
  folder
- on cPanel hosting : www,example,com    <- delete the codeiginter
  project in public_html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to delete the project within itself, you can try following.

Folder structure

```
htdocs/project
htdocs/delete_project.php
```

delete_project.php

```
function delete_files($dir) { 
  foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) { 
    if(is_dir($file)) delete_files($file); else unlink($file); 
  } rmdir($dir); 
}

delete_files("project");
//add code to delete database if you have one
```

In the admin panel, you can add button like follows

```
<a href="http://localhost/delete_project.php">Delete project<a/>
```

Same method applies to hosted environment.

**Please be careful using a file like this. Make sure the user is authorised execute the code.**